# How to make the screen scrollable on flutter (with text fields)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this piece of code for a dart page. I have 3 text fields (I will need to add 6 more). But I am getting errors such as 'Bottom overflowed'. How do I make the screen accept the 9 text fields and scrollable? I have tried to wrap the column with ListView, but it is still showing errors. I'm sure I'm not wrapping it correctly though since I am new to dart.

[Image of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky0z0.png)

//CODE FOR MAIN PAGE//

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/screens/griddashboard/griddashboard.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/screens/zakatcalculator/zakatcalculator.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    ));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items = [
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.calculate),
      label: 'Zakat Calculator',
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffde0486),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.request_page),
      label: 'Donate',
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffde0486),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.face),
      label: 'Beneficiary',
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffde0486),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.call),
      label: 'Contact Us',
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffde0486),
    ),
  ];
  Widget activeScreen;
  List<Widget> screens = [GridDashboard(), ZakatCalculator()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.activeScreen = this.screens[this._currentIndex];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 120,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/account.png'),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Account",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xff000000),
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          this.activeScreen
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          items: this.items,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

//CODE FOR ZAKATCALCULATOR PAGE//

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/common/BaseClass.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/common/stateMonitor.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'zakatcalculatorController.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/common/button_widget.dart';

class ZakatCalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ZakatCalculatorState createState() => _ZakatCalculatorState();
}

class _ZakatCalculatorState extends State<ZakatCalculator>
    with View<ZakatCalculator> {
  ZakatCalculatorController controller = new ZakatCalculatorController();

  @override
  Widget getBody() {
    return Theme(
      data: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xffde0486),
      ),
      child: ListView(
        /// Changed Part
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixText: 'Value',
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Resale value of shares',
                helperText: '',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Stock of Goods',
                helperText: '',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixText: 'Rs',
                suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xffde0486),
                ),
                labelText: 'Cash',
                helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
              autofocus: true,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Controller getController() {
    return this.controller;
  }

  @override
  InstanceNames getName() {
    return InstanceNames.ZakaatCalculator;
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace the column with ListView instead of wrapping it. If there is a genuine reason why you will be needing that calumn the you can try wrapping that column inside a SingleChildScrollView instead of ListView. And make sure to add the scrollDirection for both cases (scrollDirection: ScrollDirection.vertical)

Comment: Can you please modify the above code with the solution? I am unsure where to add the scrollDirection, I am still getting the 'A RenderFlex overflowed by 154 pixels on the bottom.' error

Comment: you don't need to specify scrollDirection if it's vertical as it's vertical by default

Comment: @Someone Check the answer I've posted.

Comment: @mightybruno Yup that's correct but it's a good practice for beginners to realize that there are such common properties like scrollDirection and stuff for Scroll widgets

Answer (score 0):

Either replace `Column` with `ListView` or wrap `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`.

It's because `Column` doesn't really care about scrolling, it just tries to render it's children.

Comment: I am still getting 'A RenderFlex overflowed by 154 pixels on the bottom.' after wrapping column with SingleChildScrollView and ListView :(

Comment: Looks like something else breaks your code. You should see the cause in the stacktrace. Could you update the question with relevant code? Ideally you could prepare an example on https://dartpad.dev

Comment: I got this error using Sarvesh code up there 'Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart;

So I think the problem is with my main. I have added the main.dart in my question. Can you check if there is a problem with it please?

Comment: Alright so try removing `SingleChildScrollView` from the inner column (the one you've added based on my answer) and add it to the outer-most Column. As I've said, `Column` doesn't care about scrolling, so you need to use a different widget.

Comment: It's good now! I've added this piece of code to both dart pages 

    body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

Answer (score 0):

Updated your widget returned by getBody function and added some more textfields to test that it's working properly :

```
Theme(
        data: new ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Color(0xffde0486),
        ),
        child: ListView(                    /// Changed Part
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixText: 'Value',
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Resale value of shares',
                  helperText: '',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Stock of Goods',
                  helperText: '',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixText: 'Rs',
                  suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xffde0486),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Cash',
                  helperText: 'Nisab Amount is Rs 30,000',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffde0486)),
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: It's still not good. I got this error 'Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/lib/main.dart;

So I think the problem is with my main. I have added the main.dart in my question. Can you check if there is a problem with it please?